# How can I add param to JPA query which will be ignored by JPA?

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-cache

There is an idea of optional caching of results of query:

```
public interface SomethingRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Something, String>
```

```
@Cacheable(value = "listOfSomething", cacheManager = "somethingCacheManager",
unless = "#cacheResults == true")
List<Something> findAllOrderByNameAsc(@Param("ignore") boolean cacheResults);
```

but I get (with and without @Param):

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: null
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:864)
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.next(Collections.java:1044)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.CriteriaQueryParameterBinder.bind(CriteriaQueryParameterBinder.java:65)
```

How can I add param which will be ignored by JPA?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a question, but rather a workaround which I implemented to solve my problem - create two methods in repository using a JPA feature (it ignores words between FIND and next reserved word) and calls different methods depending on flag

```
List<Something> findAllOrderByNameAsc();

@Cacheable(value = "listOfSomething", cacheManager = "somethingCacheManager",
unless = "#cacheResults == true")
List<Something> findCachedAllOrderByNameAsc();
```